# Sharing Mobile Internet to a WiFi network

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, android, mobile-phone

I have a home network setup (multiple devices connected to a router) but i access Internet from my Mobile Phone. I know that we can create a hotspot from my Android Mobile but that would create a whole lot of changes for devices to setup on new network. Also the network would be limited to the presence of Mobile Phone.

Is there a way to share Mobile Internet on Android 5.1 to already established WiFi Network?

Can this be done? Mobile device configured to work as a node for home network. i.e. all traffic to be directed to mobile from router. And the mobile while connected to WiFi network could access Mobile Internet (bypassing default Android Network Selection).

Answer (score 1):

You would need a router which has adequate intelligence to '[multihome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multihoming)', to switch its routing of the traffic to and from the internet to the Android mobile if present, or through your current modem if absent. Therefore, the resolution is not found in the phone hardware or software, but in the router.

Also, you would need to connect from the router to the phone by WiFi, for routers do not have Bluetooth and do not have USB ports over which the Internet connectivity can route. Most routers do not have the ability to use WiFi for the uplink.

So, to make this work, you would need to find a router which can multihome, and which can use an Internet feed connected by WiFi.

The amount of work involved to find it, and then to configure it, I suspect will dwarf the time required to just add a second WiFi network to your multiple devices at home and make that the preferred network, and then when it is absent, devices will then connect to your current connection.

And, since you are new, it is customary, when a useful answer is received, to click on the checkmark link on the left. If a better answer is provided later, you can move the checkmark to that newer answer. Folks who make contributions of time and mental effort to answer your questions receive no other compensation here.

Answer (score 0):

Short and simple answer was Proxoid https://code.google.com/p/proxoid/
Android automatically keeps Mobile Internet on when connecting to home network with no internet.
Yes there is a security loop in exposing http proxy which was intended for internal network on the web, but it did the job well.